# what the point of the len() here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning the Pyautogui module , i have came to a script where it print the position of the mouse for you  . and delete previous  output, so it look like the output is updating .

but i understand everything here but i dont understand what does *len(strPosition) exactly is there for ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui


try : 
    while True:
        x,y = pyautogui.position()
        strPosition = ' X : '+str(x).rjust(4)+' Y : '+str(y).rjust(4)
        print(strPosition,end='')
        print('\b'*len(strPosition) ,end='',flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt :

    print('\nDone.')
```

Comment: `\b*len(strpostition)` prints '\b' times the length of the strPosition. If `strposition` is, 'apple', `len(strPositon)` is 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructs like:

```
print('a string' * NUM)
```

mean: print 'a string' NUM number of times.